# Как убрать условие if и оставить только return?

Tags: c++

```
    bool g(int c, int b) {
    if (c != b)
        return(c < b);
    return(c * b > 0);

    //return((c!=b))
    //return((c!=b)*(c < b));
}
```

Comment: Ну вот так и запихнуть... В виде логического выражения. В чем проблема?

Comment: А зачем его убирать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проверьте, вам такое нужно?

```
bool g(int c, int b)
{
    return (c==b && c)||(c < b);
}
```

Если ваш код написан правильно, то это эквивалентная вашей функция.

Comment: да, все работает, а как это понять

Comment: Просто нарисовал карту Карно, получил дизъюнктивную форму и записал соответствующее булево выражение...

Comment: Умножение тоже можно убрать, `&&` достаточно проверить на неравенство 0, так как квадрат любого целого числа больше или равен 0: `return c < b || c == b && c != 0;`

Comment: @NowhereMan Вы правы, спасибо! Не обратил внимания на это. Можно даже сократить до `return c < b || c == b && c;` :)

Answer (score 2):

Ну или как вариант использовать тернарный оператор:

```
return c != b ? (c < b) : (c * b > 0);
```

Comment: мне просто сказали, что if очень затратная операция, а это, кажется, то же самое

Comment: Ну, в каких-то случаях она может быть действительно затратной. Если у Вас, например, в цикле происходят проверки. Но если говорить о данной функции, то компилятор сгенерирует более-менее похожий ассемблер для Вашего и моего вариантов. В варианте Harry, как мне кажется, сгенерируется чуть больше кода - потому что больше проверок в коде становится. Но это compiler-dependent вещи, по-разному может получится. P.S. Я, конечно, говорю о компиляции с отключенными оптимизациями.

Comment: @Sashkinzz Об этом надо было писать в вопросе, а то получается проблема XY. В этом ответе все то же самое, а в принятом - ветвлений стало в два раза больше, чем было изначально. Причем для `if` еще можно указать вероятность ветвления и чуть оптимизировать, а во всех предложенных - нет.